# How to filter JWT authentication authorities based on http header

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Basically I want to implement a filter after the JWT token is parsed and before the method is called with the ability to modify the authentication object based on an http header

### Context

In our application we have (among others) three entities related to authentication/authorization: Users, Permissions and Groups. Permissions can be directly assigned to an user or could be assigned to one of the groups a user belongs to.

Given this a JWT token looks like this:

```
{
  "username": "duck",
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "swimmer",
      "permissions": [
        "swim"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "walker",
      "permissions": [
        "walk"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "quack"
  ]
}
```

The JWT flow is setup extending `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`, and the permissions are extracted from the map of JWT claims by extending `DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter`

By using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` in the configuration I am able to annotate methods with  `@PreAuthorize`

For example:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('quack')")
public void quack();
```

This works with permissions directly assigned to the user.

However I want to receive an http header e.g: 'x-group' and add permissions from that group (if any) to the authentication object

Then, given the above 'jwt' with the http header set to `swimmer` I want to be able to invoke the following method:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('swim')")
public void
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize you didn't ask this, but establishing additional authorities from a header sounds a bit risky unless you trust its origin (e.g. it's signed or similar). It sounds odd since the reason for using OAuth is typically so that just the authorization server is issuing authorities.

Since you are already using `DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter`, I wonder if you'd be able to obtain those same extra authorities from the backend, say through an instance of `UserDetailsService`?

That said, to answer your question, you could add a filter:

```
public class XGroupFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    // ... look up current Authentication
    // ... look up and validate header
    // ... create new instance of Authentication, adding the new authorities
}
```

And then register it:

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        // ...

        http.addFilterAfter(new XGroupFilter(), OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Or, if you have the option of upgrading, then there is [new support as of Spring Security 5.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#new) which simplifies things a bit. What you are using right now is a legacy plugin project called Spring Security OAuth, but support is now [built in natively](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver). Also, that is where new features are going, making it valuable to start there, if you aren't already too far down the Spring Security OAuth road.

In that case, the configuration is still very similar:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        // ...

        http.addFilterAfter(new XGroupFilter(), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have a pretty dumb question: how could I look up for the current Authentication and mutate it?

Comment: The authentication is stored in the SecurityContextHolder. At the filter level, you just access it directly, e.g. SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); And there is a setAuthentication, too. Authentication instances themselves are immutable, so you'd need to instantiate a new one.

Comment: Thank you. It works although I had to put the filter after BasicAuthenticationFilter

Comment: Glad to hear it!